# Modal dialog not always on top with undecorated frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, modal-dialog, joptionpane

I use an undecorated JFrame with a modal dialog. The problem is the modal dialog is always on top when the frame is decorated but nto laways on top when the frame is undecorated. So when I click on my JFrame, the frame is displayed on top and the dialog go underneath.

I use this code.

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("OYE");
```

Comment: `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("OYE");`  Does that even compile?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "HelloWorld");
```

In the above one the parent is `null`. In your case set parent as your `frame`.

Example:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "HelloWorld");
```

See [showInputDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

- have to set [parent for `JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features)
- [public JOptionPane(Object message, int messageType)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#JOptionPane%28java.lang.Object,%20int%29)